# What Black Holes causes Astrophysical Jets?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, relativistic-jets

this is my first question, so here goes, I was wondering, what kind of Black Holes creates Astrophysical Jets that shows as massive clouds of particles shooting out of the Black Hole. What would be the estimate size of a Astrophysical Jet, what would the mass of black holes be to cause those jets to happen, and if possible how much energy do they generate in Joules?

Comment: For those wondering, when I say Astrophysical Jets is another word for Relativistic Jets.

Comment: Have a look: [Blandford–Znajek process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blandford%E2%80%93Znajek_process)

Comment: What would the size be for a relativistic jet if say it a stellar black hole that creates this?